# Flutter Riverpod Stream, can't stream subcollection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I have this function that is supposed to return a stream of a `List<Series>`, where `Series` is a class that has a subcollection of `Chapter`s. In the following function, the second log("HERE 2") never appears.

```
  Stream<List<Series>> getAllSeries() {
    List<Series> list = [];

    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("Series")
        .where("published", isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        Series series = Series.fromJson(doc.data());
        series.id = doc.id;
        series.chapters = [];
        list.add(series);

        List<SeriesChapter> chaptersList = [];

        log("HERE");

        _firebaseFirestore
            .collection("Series")
            .doc(series.id)
            .collection("Chapters")
            .snapshots()
            .map((snapshot) {

          log("HERE 2");

          snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
            log("HERE 3");
            SeriesChapter chapter = SeriesChapter.fromJson(doc.data());
            chapter.id = doc.id;
            chapter.screens = [];
            chaptersList.add(chapter);

            series.chapters = chaptersList;
          }).toList();
        });
      }).toList();
      return list;
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to loop through Series and then loop through its Chapters to add it to the Series instance, but somehow fails. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.